# D3 Tree Label Alternating Top and Bottom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am programming a collapsibleTree in R, which is using JavaScript. Unfortunately it looks liek this:

[image]

I can choose the y axis of the label, but they are always threated the same height. I want to have them alternating a bit on top and bottom of the knot, so that long texts dont overlap. Here is the code, I really have no clue because I never programmed JavaScript.

Thank you

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

name: 'collapsibleTree',
type: 'output',

factory: function(el, width, height) {

var i = 0,
duration = 750,
root = {},
options = {},
treemap;

// Optionally enable zooming, and limit to 1/5x or 5x of the original viewport
var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1/5, 5])
.on('zoom', function () {
  svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
})

// create our tree object and bind it to the element
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select(el).append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.append('g');

// Define the div for the tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select(el).append('div')
.attr('class', 'tooltip')
.style('opacity', 0);

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
  links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {d.y = d.depth * options.linkLength});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + source.y0 + ',' + source.x0 + ')';
  })
  .on('click', click);

  // Add tooltips, if specified in options
  if (options.tooltip) {
    nodeEnter = nodeEnter
    .on('mouseover', mouseover)
    .on('mouseout', mouseout);
  }

  // Enable zooming, if specified
  if (options.zoomable) d3.select(el).select('svg').call(zoom)

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('r', 1e-6)
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.data.fill || (d._children ? options.fill : '#fff');
  })
  .style('stroke-width', function(d) {
    return d._children ? 3 : 1;
  });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
 // .attr('dy', '1em')
 // .attr('class', 'place-label')
//  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
//    .attr('separation', '2')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    // Scale padding for label to the size of node
    var padding = (d.data.SizeOfNode || 10) + 3
    return d.children || d._children ? -1 * padding : padding;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return d.children || d._children ? 'end' : 'start';
  })
  .style('font-size', options.fontSize + 'px')
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.y + ',' + d.x + ')';
  });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.data.SizeOfNode || 10; // default radius is 10
  })
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.data.fill || (d._children ? options.fill : '#fff');
  })
  .style('stroke-width', function(d) {
    return d._children ? 3 : 1;
  })
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + source.y + ',' + source.x + ')';
  })
  .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
  .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
  .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
  .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', 'g')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  // Potentially, this may one day be mappable
  // .style('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.data.linkWidth || 1 })
  .attr('d', function(d){
    var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 }
    return diagonal(o, o)
  });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
    return diagonal(o, o)
  })
  .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = 'M ' + s.y + ' ' + s.x + ' C ' +
    (s.y + d.y) / 2 + ' ' + s.x + ', ' +
    (s.y + d.y) / 2 + ' ' + d.x + ', ' +
    d.y + ' ' + d.x;

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
    // Hide the tooltip after clicking
    tooltip.transition()
    .duration(100)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    // Update Shiny inputs, if applicable
    if (options.input) {
      var nest = {},
      obj = d;
      // Navigate up the list and recursively find parental nodes
      for (var n = d.depth; n > 0; n--) {
        nest[options.hierarchy[n-1]] = obj.data.name
        obj = obj.parent
      }
      Shiny.onInputChange(options.input, nest)
    }
  }

  // Show tooltip on mouseover
  function mouseover(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style('opacity', .9);

    // Show either a constructed tooltip, or override with one from the data
    tooltip.html(
      d.data.tooltip || d.data.name + '<br>' +
      options.attribute + ': ' + d.data.WeightOfNode
    )
    // Make the tooltip font size just a little bit bigger
    .style('font-size', (options.fontSize + 1) + 'px')
    .style('left', (d3.event.layerX) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.layerY - 30) + 'px');
  }
  // Hide tooltip on mouseout
  function mouseout(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style('opacity', 0);
  }
}

return {
  renderValue: function(x) {
    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(x.data, function(d) { return d.children; });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Attach options as a property of the instance
    options = x.options;

    // Update the canvas with the new dimensions
    svg = svg.attr('transform', 'translate('
    + options.margin.left + ',' + options.margin.top + ')')

    // width and height, corrected for margins
    var heightMargin = height - options.margin.top - options.margin.bottom,
    widthMargin = width - options.margin.left - options.margin.right;
    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    treemap = d3.tree().size([heightMargin, widthMargin])
    .separation(separationFun);

    // Calculate a reasonable link length, if not otherwise specified
    if (!options.linkLength) {
      options.linkResponsive = true
      options.linkLength = widthMargin / options.hierarchy.length
      if (options.linkLength < 10) {
        options.linkLength = 10 // Offscreen or too short
      }
    }

    // Optionally collapse after the second level
    if (options.collapsed) root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if(d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }
  },

  resize: function(width, height) {
    // Resize the canvas
    d3.select(el).select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

    // width and height, corrected for margins
    var heightMargin = height - options.margin.top - options.margin.bottom,
    widthMargin = width - options.margin.left - options.margin.right;

    // Calculate a reasonable link length, if not originally specified
    if (options.linkResponsive) {
      options.linkLength = widthMargin / options.hierarchy.length
      if (options.linkLength < 10) {
        options.linkLength = 10 // Offscreen or too short
      }
    }
    // Update the treemap to fit the new canvas size
    treemap = d3.tree().size([heightMargin, widthMargin])
    .separation(separationFun);
    update(root)
  },
  // Make the instance properties available as a property of the widget
  svg: svg,
  root: root,
  options: options
  };
 }
});

function separationFun(a, b) {
var height = a.data.SizeOfNode + b.data.SizeOfNode,
// Scale distance to SizeOfNode, if defined
distance = (height || 20) / 10;
return (a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : distance);
};
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to narrow your code down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so remove the tooltip/resize and other unnecessary stuff. Also, please add some example data so we know what format to expect.

Comment: Did it with  

       .attr('dy', function(d) {
 var over_under= (d.depth % 2==0) ? '1em' : '-1em';
        return over_under;
      })